# How to stop reactor websocket connection

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket, reactor-netty

Given this example from reactor docs:

```
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.create();

        client.websocket()
              .uri("wss://echo.websocket.org")
              .handle((inbound, outbound) -> {
                  inbound.receive()
                         .asString()
                         .take(1)
                         .subscribe(System.out::println);

                  final byte[] msgBytes = "hello".getBytes(CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1);
                  return outbound.send(Flux.just(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(msgBytes), Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(msgBytes)))
                                 .neverComplete();
              })
              .blockLast();
    }
}
```

How to stop and disconnect from websocket completely when `take(1)` or any other condition is true? Now it hangs indefinitely and does not exit

Answer (score 0):

It seems this sample can be fixed by removing `neverComplete` as follows:

```
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.create();

        client.websocket()
        .uri("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        .handle((inbound, outbound) -> {

            return outbound.sendString(Mono.just("hello"), CharsetUtil.UTF_8)
                    .then()
                    .thenMany(inbound.receive()
                            .asString()
                            .take(1)
                            .doOnNext(System.out::println));
        })
        .blockLast();
    }
}
```